# .htaccess adds /var/www/html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

We have had our Website running on an older Apache2 instance with a large `.htaccess` file for redirects of old URLs to new ones. Since we have a lot of equal sub-URLs the redirect looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)old/url(.*)$ new/url [L,R=301]
```

This worked like a charm.

For example `www.example.com/a/old/url` got redirected to `www.example.com/a/new/url` and also worked for `/b/` or `/c/`.

With the new Apache (2.4.54) the redirect doesn't work as expected  since it redirects as follows:

`www.example.com/var/www/html/new/url`

What am I doing wrong? Why does it place the base path of the website in front?

I've tried to google as good as possible but couldn't find anything. I would expect any weird path that I don't know of is set in the wrong way.

I'm not very deep into `.htaccess` which makes it hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: Something is strange here ... That ``RewriteRUle`` you posted certainly will _not_ do what you claim it does.

Comment: About the actual issue: you probably have a ``RewriteBase`` set to that value?

Comment: What version of Apache were you running before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)old/url(.*)$ new/url [L,R=301]
> ```
>
> This worked like a charm.
>
> For example `www.example.com/a/old/url` got redirected to `www.example.com/a/new/url` and also worked for `/b/` or `/c/`.

It would only do that if you also had a `RewriteBase /a` directive defined elsewhere in the config file. (Although it's not clear how it would work the same for `/b/` or `/c/`, unless you have other directives that are helping. Unless you mean that it redirects from `/b/` or `/c/` to `/a/`? In which case, the `RewriteBase` directive alone is what is enabling this to work.)

> With the new Apache (2.4.54) the redirect doesn't work as expected since it redirects as follows: `www.example.com/var/www/html/new/url`

That will happen if `RewriteBase` is **not** defined as mentioned above.

This applies to both Apache 2.2 and 2.4.

However, it's also possible that `RewriteBase` is/was defined in a parent config and `RewriteOptions MergeBase` was set (which propagates the setting to child configs). A further complication is that in later versions of Apache 2.2 (specifically 2.2.23 and later) and early versions of Apache 2.4 (specifically 2.4.0 to 2.4.3) this was actually the default (arguably buggy) behavior. So, if you are upgrading from one of these "buggy" versions of Apache, it's possible this was "just working".

The `RewriteBase` directive defines the URL-path that is prefixed to relative substitution strings (`new/url` is a relative substitution string). If no `RewriteBase` is defined then the directory-prefix (ie. the absolute file-path of where the `.htaccess` file is located) is added back - which is resulting in your malformed redirect.

For external "redirects" it is often preferable to use a root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (scheme + hostname) substitution string. For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)old/url(.*)$ /a/new/url [L,R=301]
```

The above is no longer dependent on the `RewriteBase` directive, since the *substitution* string (ie. `/a/new/url`) is no longer *relative*.

However, `^(.*)old/url(.*)$` is the same as simply `old/url`, which is rather too general. Perhaps something like the following would be preferable:

```
 RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/old/url /a/new/url [L,R=301]
```

The above redirects `/a/old/url` or `/b/old/url` or `/c/old/url<anything>` to `/a/new/url`.

OR, redirect to the same URL-path (ie. `a`, `b` or `c`) using a backreference:

```
 RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/old/url /$1/new/url [L,R=301]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will have been cached by the browser (and possibly any intermediary caches). Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

#### Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: The missing RewriteBase was the problem. Obviously we've been on a buggy Apache System before. Can't check that anymore, sadly. With the RewriteBase everything works again. Thanks a lot!